# Required attribute not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
Public Class Duration 
{
  [Required]
  Public DurationUnit Unit
  [Required]
  Public int Length
}

Public Class Employee
{
  [RequiredAttribute]
  public virtual Duration NotificationLeadTime { get; set; }
}
```

The fields *`Unit`* and *`Length`*, when not suplied are getting highlighted in Red but the error message is not getting displayed.

I tries also giving `[Required(ErrorMessage="sadfdsf")]`,but this is also not working.
I also tried inheriting the class with `IValidatableObject` but that also didn't work.

How to display the error message ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use properties, not fields:

```
public class Duration 
{
    [Required]
    public DurationUnit Unit { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

In order to display the corresponding error message use the `Html.ValidationMessageFor` helper.

For example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NotificationLeadTime.Unit)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NotificationLeadTime.Unit)
```

By the way it doesn't really make sense to decorate a non-nullable type such as `int` with the `[Required]` attribute because those types always have a default value. You should make it a nullable integer instead. Same remark stands for the `DurationUnit` property if `DurationUnit` is an enum.